# API: Is it better to have a slower, conventient API implementation or a faster, more complex one?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, ruby-on-rails-3, middleware

I am using Ruby on Rails 3 and I am developing API for my applications.

I have a web client app that make HTTP requests to a web server app. However the web application handles incoming request in the controller and responds like this:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html {redirect_to @account}
  ...
  format.json {
    render :json => @account.to_json, :status => 200
  }
  format.xml {
    render :xml => @account.to_xml, :status => 200
  }
end
```

At this time I don't use Rack middlewares because it is very "convenient" to respond using `respond_to`, and you don't have to change anything more in your application other than the controller. Anyway, I know that using middleware is faster in responding than the above approach, but I should implement responses for every HTTP request, maybe intercepting them URI.

**What do you advice about? It is better "convenience" and "slowness"** (like the code above) **or "complexity" and "fastest"?**

Comment: There is on one answer that's correct. For small sites, the slow but convenient code is probably perfectly adequate. For a large site that handles a lot of traffic, it may be worthwhile to work on improving performance at the expense of complexity. One easy way is to estimate the time necessary to implement the faster method, and the cost of servers for the site (including administration, power, etc.) Do what minimizes long-term cost.

Comment: I'd add that the TDD philosophy is: write just enough code to make your tests pass.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Premature optimization is the root of all evil](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_optimization#When_to_optimize). If the code is fast enough for your purposes using the design that you prefer, **keep using it**. If you find that it's not fast enough, *then* you can look at options for speeding it up.

Comment: +1 I prefer the 97% quote but ... :) It might also be worth to note 1) the *actual* problems are likely not known up-front (a different/"complicated" design might be required, but it may be different than an initial approach, e.g. the "simple" can work as a prototype) 2) that a *used* application has a better chance of generating *$$$* which can then be used to make said application better